# Is there any way to get iphoto metadata (faces, tags) onto the file information?

Tags: macos, photos, metadata, iphoto, spotlight

So faces, places, tags, appear in the jpeg metadata? I want to be able to find them in spotlight, have them if I change programs, etc.   If not, does anyone know whether aperture 3 can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The faces data is not stored inside the JPGs, but in a specific file (face.db if I remember well) inside the iphoto library package.

Comment: Right- I'm wondering if there's a way to get it to copy them to the files somehow...